# How would you replace the now deprecated .accentColor in this instance?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following along with the "Build a workout app for Apple Watch" video from WWDC'21. At one point they use the now deprecated `.accentColor` modifier to change the color of text in a sub-view.

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    @State private var durationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                SummaryMetricView(title: "Total Time", value: durationFormatter.string(from: 30 * 60 + 15) ?? "")
                    .accentColor(.yellow)
                
                SummaryMetricView(title: "Total Distance", value: Measurement(value: 1625, unit: UnitLength.meters)
                        .formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)))
                    .accentColor(.green)
                
                SummaryMetricView(title: "Total Energy", value: Measurement(value: 96, unit: UnitEnergy.kilocalories)
                        .formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .workout, numberFormatStyle: FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>().precision(.fractionLength(0)))))
                    .accentColor(.pink)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SummaryMetricView: View {
    var title: String
    var value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
        Text(value)
            .font(.system(.title2, design: .rounded).lowercaseSmallCaps())
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Divider()
    }
}
```

I tried replacing `.accentColor(.yellow)` with `.tint(.yellow)` and removing the `.foregroundColor(.accentColor)` modifier from `SummaryMetricView` but this had no effect. I also tried changing `.foregroundColor(.accentColor)` to `.foregroundColor(.tint)` but this does not compile. Is there any way to achieve the same effect without passing in a color to `SummaryMetricView`, ie. use a modifier the way `.accentColor(.pink)` was used?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a view modifier like this, then you can use `.foregroundStyle`:

```swift
struct SummaryView: View {
  ...
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      SummaryMetricView()
        .foregroundStyle(.green)

      SummaryMetricView()
        .foregroundStyle(.orange)
    }
  }
}

struct SummaryMetricView: View {
  ...
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello 1")
    Text("Hello 2")
      .foregroundStyle(.red) // Will not be overridden
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same. It's an inversion of `accentColor`. With `accentColor` you mark anything you want it to apply to inside the view. With `foregroundStyle` you have to mark anything you don't want the `foregroundStyle` to apply to in the view. Sort of analogous to blacklist vs whitelist.